# Arrange rectangles to anchor points without overlap

Tags: performance, algorithm, geometry, overlap, rectangles

I have a set of rectangles of different size. Each rectangle has an anchor point on the 2 dimensional plane where the center of the rectangle should be placed. The rectangles should not overlap and the center of a rectangle should be as close as possible to its anchor point. So if the center of the rectangle_i is vector c_i and its anchor point is vector a_i then the target function would be min(sum_i((c_i - a_i)^2)). I am looking for an algorithm that approaches the optimal solution as much as possible in O(n).

The rectangles can not be rotated.

The inputs of the problem are:

- the size of n rectangle
- for each rectangle the coordinates of the associated anchor point.

The output should be the position of the rectangles i.e. coordinates of the center of each rectangle.

In the example below x signs the center of the rectangle and o the anchor points:

```
             +-----------+    
             |           |    
+-----------+|     x     |    
|           || o         |    
|     x     |+-----------+    
|         o | +-------------+ 
+-----------+ |  o          | 
   +---------+|      x      | 
   |       o ||             | 
   |    x    |+-------------+ 
   |         |                
   +---------+
```

Comment: You must be missing something in this description.  What prevents you from just putting the anchor points on the centers to achieve a target value of zero every time?  What are the inputs and outputs of the algorithm you're looking for?

Comment: sry if I was not clear enough, I added some more details about input / output.

Comment: Ahh!  That make sense.  I'll think about this.  I'm almost certain it's NP hard. You can certainly get an _optimal_, though probably not _optimum_ solution by simulating a damped, constrained mass-spring system, much as graph layout algorithms work.  Use a spring between each anchor and corresponding center.  Calculate normal forces by collision detection.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! I am also quite sure that this is NP hard problem, but I should generate the results in a video stream (30-60 fps) on an embedded ARM processor. Actually my platform is iOS7 that has a very cool physics engine called UIDynamics, and I was amazed that you suggested springs + collisions as it is exactly the solution with that I came up. But I would be really curious in some more theoretical background so I posted my question anyway :)

Comment: I was also wondering if this problem has something common with [Automatic Label Placement problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement) mostly dealt with in cartography and whether the algorithms used to solve it could be applied also here.